# Javafx tableview scrolling is too slow

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, tableview, fxml

I've made a Tableview in Javafx that show 100.000 rows ,but the problem's the scrolling is too slow , please if any one has any idea about that !!..

[bitbucket.org/JdevY/tableview-performance](http://%20bitbucket.org/JdevY/tableview-performance)

// it works well if i make readOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue()) but 
I make it like readOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getId_student) it doesn't work !!

```
id_student.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student,String>("id_student") {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, String> param) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getId_student());
        }

    });
    fname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("fname") {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, String> param) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getFname());
        }

    });
    lname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("lname") {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, String> param) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getLname());
        }

    });
    nameFather.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("nameFather") {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, String> param) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getNameFather());
        }

    });
    birthDay.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("birthDay") {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, String> param) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getBirthDay());
        }

    });
    birthPlace.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("birthPlace") {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, String> param) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getBirthPlace());
        }

    });
    email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("email") {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, String> param) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getEmail());
        }

    });
    tel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("tel") {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, String> param) {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(param.getValue().getTel());
        }

    });
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of the `Student` class? Furthermore: Why are you extending `PropertyValueFactory` instead of simply implementing `Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student,String>,ObservableValue<String>>`? Also using `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` instead of `SimpleObjectProperty` or `SimpleStringProperty` doesn't make sense... It's just as writeable as it's superclass `SimpleObjectProperty`/`SimpleStringProperty`.

Comment: Create and post an actual [MCVE]. It's pretty much impossible to answer questions about performance without a complete example.

Comment: thanks for replying ,a putted the code on bitbucket : https://bitbucket.org/JdevY/tableview-performance

Comment: Do you happen to use Linux? Is some or most of the data in the table in a complex or right-to-left language (e.g. Arabic, Hindi, Farsi, Hebrew etc)?